# Bounded Convergence for derivating under the integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n(x)$ be a sequence of uniformly bounded real valued functions defined on a finite measurable space, which converges pointwise to $f(x)$. By bounded convergence theorem, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_n(x)d\mu(x)=\int f(x)d\mu(x)$. That is, we do not need a dominating function to pass the limit.

Now consider we have $f(x,t)$, which is uniformly bounded in $t$, and its derivative with respect to $t$ exists. Is it true that $$\frac{d}{dt}\int f(x,t)d\mu(x)=\int \frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}d\mu(x)$$

That is, can we dispense of a dominating function for the derivative?

Comment: a side note: the finiteness of the measure space and the uniform bound indeed defines implicitly a dominating function, that is, there is some $M>0$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le M$ for all $n$ and all $x$

Comment: about the question: yes, there is a theorem that shows that, but you dont need that the measure space would be finite, also some others conditions can be weakened a bit. Take a look at theorem 3.18 of *Analysis III* of Amann and Escher

Comment: Not true. The hypothesis does not even guarantee the existence of the integral on RHS.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy right! We need some other conditions, as that the region of integration is enough nice (convex, or so) and that the derivative respect to $t$ is continuous in this region